# Setting fields in controller to use in Spring Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

Well, I had to instantiate Controller in order to test it. Moreover, I needed to set in that controller some fields which are not Spring beans.
I've found a few ways of solving:

---

- ReflectionTestUtils.setField()
- Creating constructor in controller and autowire it

Like that:

```
@Autowired
public Controller(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}
```

the above method doesn't actually work for me, because I can't autowire as Player isn't a Spring Bean.

- Creating constructor in the controller and NOT autowire it

This way:

```
    public Controller() {

    }

    public Controller(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
```

In addition, I have to create a no-args constructor. Without it several exceptions are thrown, for example, *"Failed to load ApplicationContext"*.

---

So, after all, I decided to use the last method and in testing I just instantiate controller this way:

```
public class ControllerTest {
    private Player player = new Player();

    private Controller controller = new Controller(player);
}
```

**What I basically want to know** is if I'm doing everything right. And if there are some other ways to set fields(which are not Spring Beans) in the Controller and use that Controller and its fields in testing.

Comment: there is an annotation if you are using mockito called @InjectMock you can look at that

Comment: @Naveen I do not use Mockito there and don't use mocks except Spring's mockMvc

Comment: How did you creating and initialize your controller in application (not test) ?? I think in this way you should also creating test objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Boot you can use [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) to set up a limited Spring context and `@MockBean` to create mock beans needed by your controller as explained in [Testing Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class WebMockTest {

  @MockBean
  private Player player;

...
```

You should avoid `ReflectionTestUtils.setField()`, your controller should have either a constructor or setter for the field if it's important for unit testing.